# Sublime Text 3 Bugged up after uninstalling Materialize package

Tags: sublimetext3

So I recently installed Materialize package on my Sublime Text 3 just to try it out, and didn't like it. So I went ahead to remove it. After removing, My Sublime got all messed up. I couldn't see my files. Can't open package control. The screen itself is messed up. I tried Uninstalling and Reinstalling many times, and I'm still experiencing the same problem.

Please help me fix this, Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @amit-gurbani Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your settings still refer to the old theme, which doesn't exist any more. You can follow the instructions at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html to revert to a clean state, or just edit your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file to remove the old `theme` setting. (The Preferences menu -> Browse Packages will be visible even when you are having theme problems.)